Camera crop working on Android 10. Not working on Android 11 or 12
Below is a very small gitHub project for image cropping from camera pic or gallery pic.
So, on the android java side it is using the 'edmodo' image cropper library-
com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper
But it is crashing when cropping from camera. Gallery image cropping is working correctly. Only problem is with camera.
Camera cropping is working fine on Android 10 and 6
Camera cropping not working (crashing) on Android 11 and 12
This is the android java app -
https://github.com/syed-nw/image-cropper
This is the library code -
(com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper) -
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/tree/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper
How do I make camera crop to work on latest android 11 and 12 and even later android versions ???

Can you add crash logs also in the question? Please take screenshot of android studio logcat or copy paste logs when crash occurs in android 11 and above
